# Want to save categories tag into mongoDB when user create new post but could not see any categories table

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb

I am building a blog app with React and Node.
I want to save the categories tag when a user creates a new post. But It did not save the categories tag into the categories table on MongoDB

I am using:

```
"react": "^18.2.0",
node:v14.18.1
```

Here is the js file for the user to create a new post in React.

```
import { useContext, useState } from "react";
import "./write.css";
import { Context } from "../../context/Context";
import NoImage from "../../images/noImage.jpeg"
import { axiosInstance } from "../../config";

import ReactQuill from 'react-quill';
import 'react-quill/dist/quill.snow.css';

export default function Write() {
  const [title, setTitle] = useState("");
  const [desc, setDesc] = useState("");
  const [cats, setCats] = useState([]);
  const [file, setFile] = useState(null);
  const { user } = useContext(Context);

console.log(desc);  

  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const newPost = {
      username: user.username,
      title,
      desc,
      categories: cats,
    };

    if (file) {
      const data = new FormData();
      const filename = Date.now() + file.name;
      data.append("name", filename);
      data.append("file", file);
      newPost.photo = filename;
      try {
        await axiosInstance.post("/upload", data);
      } catch (err) {}
    }

    

    try {
      // First, create the categories and post together
      const res = await axiosInstance.post("/posts", newPost);
      window.location.replace("/post/" + res.data._id);
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }

  };

  

    const putCatHandler = (e) => {
      if(e.keyCode !== 32) return 
      //avoid space key at the first letter
      const value = e.target.value.trimStart();

      //add all element
      if(!value.trim()) return 
      setCats([...cats, value]);
      
      e.target.value = "";
      
    }

    const deleteCat = (index) => {
        setCats(cats.filter((cat, i) => i !== index));
    }

  
  return (
    <div className="writeWrapper">
      <div className="write">
        {/* box1 */}
        {
          !file ? <img className="writeNoImg" src={NoImage} alt="" />
          : <img className="writeImg" src={URL.createObjectURL(file)} alt="" />
        }

        {/* box2 */}
        <form className="writeForm" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>

          <div className="writeFormGroup">
            <input
              type="file"
              id="fileInput"
              onChange={(e) => setFile(e.target.files[0])}
              required={true}
            />
            <input
              type="text"
              placeholder="Title..."
              className="writeInput"
              autoFocus={true}
              onChange={e=>setTitle(e.target.value)}
              required={true}
              autoCapitalize={true}
            />
          </div>

          <div className="writeFormGroup">
                {
                    cats.map((cat, index) => (
                        <div className="catInputItem" key={index}>
                            <span className="text">{cat}</span>
                            <span className="close" onClick={() => deleteCat(index)}>&times;</span>
                        </div>
                    ))
                }
                <input type="text" onKeyDown={putCatHandler} autoCapitalize={true} disabled={cats.length >= 5 ? true : false} required={true}  className="catsUserInput" style={cats.length >= 5 ? {marginBottom:'15px'} : {}} placeholder="Press space key after typing category..."/>
                {
                  cats.length >= 5 ? (<span style={{ color: "red"}}>You can put only 5 categories</span>)
                                   : <></> 
                }
          </div>

          <div className="writeFormGroup">
            <ReactQuill theme="snow" className="editor" value={desc} onChange={setDesc} />
          </div>
          
          <div className="writeFormGroup">
            <button className="writeSubmit" type="submit">
              Publish
            </button>
          </div>
          
        </form>
      </div>
      
    </div>
  );
}
```

Here is my posts.js as server-side used with Node:

```
const router = require("express").Router();
const User = require("../models/User.js");
const Post = require("../models/Post.js");
const Category = require("../models/Category.js");
const bcrypt = require("bcrypt");

//Create post
router.post("/", async (req, res) => {
    const { categories, ...postData } = req.body;
  
    try {
      // 1. Find or create categories
      const categoryPromises = categories.map(async (catName) => {
        const existingCategory = await Category.findOne({ name: catName });
        if (existingCategory) {
          return existingCategory;
        } else {
          const newCategory = new Category({ name: catName });
          return await newCategory.save();
        }
      });
  
      const resolvedCategories = await Promise.all(categoryPromises);
  
      // 2. Create a new post with the resolved categories
      const newPost = new Post({
        ...postData,
        categories: resolvedCategories.map((cat) => cat._id),
      });
  
      const savedPost = await newPost.save();
      res.status(200).json(savedPost);
    } catch (err) {
      res.status(500).json(err);
    }
  });
  

//update post
router.put("/:id", async (req,res) => {
    try {
        const post = await Post.findById(req.params.id);
        if(post.username === req.body.username){
            try {
                const updatedPost = await Post.findByIdAndUpdate(
                    req.params.id,
                    {
                        $set: req.body,
                    },
                    {
                        new: true
                    }
                );
                res.status(200).json(updatedPost);
            } catch (error) {
                res.status(500).json(error);
            }
        }else {
            res.status(401).json("You can update only your post.");
        }
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(500).json(error);
    }
});

//Delete post
router.delete("/:id", async (req,res) => {
    try {
        const post = await Post.findById(req.params.id);
        if(post.username === req.body.username){
            try{
                await post.delete();
                res.status(200).json("Post has been deleted...");
            } catch (error) {
                res.status(500).json(error);
            }
        }else {
            res.status(401).json("You can delete only your post.");
        }
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(500).json(error);
    }
});

//GET post
router.get("/:id", async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const post = await Post.findById(req.params.id);
        res.status(200).json(post);
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(500).json(error);
    }
})

//Get all posts
router.get("/", async (req, res) => {
    const username = req.query.user;
    const catName = req.query.cat;

    try {
        let posts;
        if(username){
            posts = await Post.find({ username });
        } else if(catName){
            posts = await Post.find({
                categories:{
                    $in: [catName],
                },
            });
        } else {
            posts = await Post.find();
            
        }
        res.status(200).json(posts);
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(500).json(error);
    }
})


module.exports = router;
```

Here is the model of Category:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const CategorySchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    name: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
  },
  { timestamps: true }
);

module.exports = mongoose.model("Category", CategorySchema);
```

Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Not really an answer but more like a comment that might help you find the solution.

Since you don't see new category being created there are 2 possible reasons for that:

1. Client Side
2. Server Side

To understand why you need to ensure that your server getting information about categories. If you see it on the server and the format is what you expect then you can narrow it down further

```
//Create post
router.post("/", async (req, res) => {
    const { categories, ...postData } = req.body;
    
    console.log('!!Categories', categories); // check this log
// rest of it...
```

Once you confirm it you can go step by step to understand at which point it starts to fail by adding more logs along the way.

Hope it helps. Once you narrow down the issue it will be more actionable for you or community to help you.